# React Native Formik handleSubmit does not read return values from function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

Good day!

Im having a weird experience using formik today,
I am currently working on an app that uses formik to handle forms and will do an API request inside the onSubmit() function of formik.

Every thing went well except when i use API request and wait for it's callback.
Somehow the things inside the function of onSubmit will work properly but the API callback value does not return unless i perform a UI Change in the app itself (like pressing random spots on my screen to trigger ui change).

Here is a look of my onSubmit function of formik

```
onSubmit={values => {
                      console.log("before")
                      let response = FunctionWithApiRequest(values);
                      console.log("after")
                      response.then((res) => {
                         console.log(res)
                      })
          }}
```

and here is my function with api request inside

```
const FunctionWithApiRequest = (credentials) => {
    return fetch(`${AppConfig.HOSTNAME}/v2/auth/signup`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

The return "responseJson" will only appear inside the onsubmit function when i perform a UI Change (like clicking random spots in my react native screen)

i was wondering what is the problem and what cause the bug.

Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the haul bundler, when you enable dugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can do this in a separate function with await and async.For instance

```
async handleSubmit(){
let {credentials} = this.state
let data = await this.props.FunctionWithApiRequest(credentials)
this.setState({returnedData: data})
}
```

And now in your textInput/formik

```
onSubmit={()=>this.handleSubmit()}
```

I assume you have made the request api function in actions.file, not in the same file.Am i right?So what i have done is just put await before call.Which means next line will execute only when you have response returned.Comment down if you have any issue.

Comment: I tried this kind of syntax but it returns the same result as the one above. i still need to touch or perform something before the console.log(return_value) shows up